# Not able to connect tp SQL Server database from ASP.NET Core app inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-container

I have created an ASP.NET Core app which will use SQL Server as its backend which is installed on the local machine. I am using Visual Studio to develop the ASP.NET Core web app and able to connect to SQL Server without any issues if I am running the application through Visual Studio.

After deploying the app inside the Docker container, application is not able to communicate with the SQL Server which is installed on the host machine.

I have enabled "TCP" connection and enabled the port in "Advanced Firewall Settings" on my local machine. I am able to connect to SQL Server with the IpAddress along with PORT (`IpAddress, PORT`)

Below is the command which I am using it to deploy the image inside the Docker container:

```
docker run -d -p 5061:80 --name mycurrentserviceapicontainer mycurrentserviceapi --network="host"
```

Information:

I am able to access the API which is not having DB Connection, but API which has functionality related to DB connection causing an issue.

Issue:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=5; handshake=435; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=14251;

Connection String:

> Server=ipaddress,49172;Database=DockerDb;User=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

**49172** - It is the TCP Port and enabled this Port in the Inbound Rule of Windows Firewall and able to connect it through Sql Server Management Studio.

I am not sure why i am getting this issue. I have searched many articles, nothing helped me to rectify this issue. Does any one come across this issue? Please provide your suggestion on this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could share your connection string, more information on your network computers if more than one, and also you might want to check the usage of --network="host" in the docker command.

Do you have access to the db by using telnet or any similar command?

Comment: This is all post-login. So the connection was made, handshakes were established but no login actions were made. Can you confirm the credentials you're using are SQL Server authentication, and that they have perms to the DB itself?

Comment: @Dockstar, Thanks for your Response. Yes, I am using SQL Server Authentication. Connection String **Server=<nat ipAddress,49172>;Database=DockerDb;User=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true**. It has Permission to the DB as i am able to connect it through Sql Server Management Studio and also by running the application through Visual Studio and "IISExpress". Please share your Thoughts on this. Thanks.

Comment: @CristianCordova, Connection String **Server=<nat ipAddress,49172>;Database=DockerDb;User=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true**. **49172** is the TCP Port and I have added it in my inbound rule in Windows Firewall to accept the Port. I am able to connect it through Sql Server Management Studio and Visual Studio & "IIS Express". Please share your Thoughts on this. Thanks.

Comment: Jic, I would recommend you to use a port between 1024 and 49151, instead of 49172. [Read this for more insight](https://www.w3schools.in/cyber-security/ports-and-its-security/).  
  
You can try to disable the firewall temporarily to see if you can access the database.

Comment: You're referring to a NAT IP address. Is that the same IP address you would use to access the SQL server from your local machine (IE when you use Visual Studio and IIS)? IE It's on a remote network? Or is it a VM you're running locally behind Hyper V or Virtualbox with a natted address? If it's a VM with a nat'td address you may want to try "host" mode for networking as running the traffic via the host network would render the same result as you doing it with IIS etc.

Comment: @CristianCordova, Thanks for your response. I tried with **"1025"**, restarted the Sql Service, enabled the inbound Rule and disabled the **firewall** as well, still getting the "TimedOut" message when connecting to the Database. I am using **Docker For Windows** and working with **Linux Container**. Is there anything i need to do with these. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Dockstar, Thanks for your response. I am using the same IP Address and Port to connect to SQL Server from Visual Studio and IIS and it is working without any issues. Everything i am doing it in my Local Machine. I am using **Docker For Windows and working with Linux Container**. Is there anything i need to do with these. Is there any configuration i need to do in Docker Container (or) in Run Command. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Found some relevant information: I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST
The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.

The gateway is also reachable as gateway.docker.internal.

[Check this link for more info.](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/)